# How to prevent CSS animation on page load?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have an animation, which is taking care of the fading in and out transition on button hover state.

The problem is that the default animation (`-webkit-animation: off-state 1s;`) is firing off on page load. How do I make it active only after first hover state?

I know how to achieve this using CSS transitions. **I am looking for a solution using animation/keyframes.**

**HTML**

```
<div class="button"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.button { background: #000; width: 20px; height: 20px; -webkit-animation: off-state 1s; }
.button:hover { -webkit-animation: on-state 1s; }

@-webkit-keyframes on-state {
  0% { height: 20px; }
  100% { height: 100px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes off-state {
  0% { height: 100px; }
  100% { height: 20px; }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ItUZoRU/1/)

Comment: Add a class using a tiny bit of javascript on hover

Comment: @Zeaklous is this not possible with css alone?

Comment: No, unless you simply mean [like this](http://jsbin.com/ItUZoRU/3/edit). There currently is no way to add a class with pure CSS

Comment: @Zeaklous That's using transitions, which are unfortunately not as flexible as animation.

Comment: Agreed, I realize that completely. Like I said above there is no way to add a class with pure CSS. I'm still not clear as to what your end goal here is, could you provide a working js version?

Comment: The answer below does what I want.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Zeaklous, this can be done using JavaScript, e.g. using jQuery:

```
$('.button').one('mouseout', function () { $(this).addClass('alt-animation'); });
```

and moving the `animation` rule to `.alt-animation` class:

```
.button { background: #000; width: 20px; height: 20px; }
.button.alt-animation { -webkit-animation: off-state 1s; }
.button:hover { -webkit-animation: on-state 1s; }
```

Ideally, there should be CSS only alternative.